# Compare two values and add them to list if they match - code improvement

Tags: python, performance, loops, comparison

I am working with medical history data and need to figure out to find the series of diagnoses a patient has had.
I have a large database which includes data on unique ID, diagnosis, time of contact with healthcare, and so on.

I made some dummy data here to illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ["ID","DIAG","TYPE","IN","OUT","GENDER","DOB"]
diags = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2000,7)),columns=columns)
diags_counter = diags.groupby("ID")["DIAG"].count().to_frame()
diags_counter.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True)
```

I reset the index, since the IDs in the database are more complex, and using .loc wouldn't work.

My idea was to make a list or dictionary of a list of dataframes for each patient, i.e. a patient might have only one diagnosis, while another might have 2 or more.
Following code is working, but extremely slow, and since I have over half a million patients, this is not going to work:

```
diags_seq = []
for i in range(0,len(diags_counter)):
  X= []
  for j in range(0,len(diags)):
    if diags_counter.ID.iloc[i] == diags.ID.iloc[j]:
      X.append(diags.iloc[j])
  diags_seq.append(X)
  print(f"\r{i+1} of {len(diags_counter)} found", end="")
```

Any help to how to approach this otherwise would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be fine:

```
unique_id = diags.ID.unique()
dict_of_specifics_id = {}
for id in unique_id:
   dict_of_specifics_id[id] = {}
   dict_of_specifics_id[id]['id_counter'] = 0
   dict_of_specifics_id[id]['diag_list'] = []
for index, row in diags.iterrows():
   dict_of_specifics_id[row.ID]['id_counter']+=1
   dict_of_specifics_id[row.ID]['diag_list'].append(row.DIAG)
dict_of_specifics_id
```

Output:

```
{21: {'id_counter': 16,
  'diag_list': [45, 41, 92, 91, 62, 54, 16, 18, 23, 18, 0, 47, 9, 45, 2, 61]},
```

Where 21 is ID and diag_list is list of diagnosis to this ID. id_counter is actualy len of diag_list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems to work much faster!

However, I removed ".DIAG" for the appending to get all data about the diagnosis.
But it is a little messy, since it ends up being a dictionary including another dictionary, including a list of pd series.
How should I best change the code to have the list of series within the original dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. You'd like to add all the parameters to the dict which I name dict_of_specifics_id?

Comment: ```
dict_of_specifics_id[row.ID]['diag_list'].append(row) #changed row
```
I changed just this one line, because I wanted not only the Diagnosis, but also data on "TYPE", "IN", "OUT" and so on.

However, it ends up being kinda messy, because "dict_of_specifics_id" ends up being a list of series within a dictionary, which in turn is also in a dictionary.
I was thinking the most clean result would be a dictionary that includes either one or more series or a DataFrame, where each row is one diagnosis?
Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

So after some tweaking, I ended up with using the following:

```
dict_of_specifics_id = {}
for id in unique_id:
   dict_of_specifics_id[id] = {}
   dict_of_specifics_id[id]['diag_list'] = []
for index, row in diags.iterrows():
   dict_of_specifics_id[row.ID]['diag_list'].append(row)

seq_diags_list = list(dict_of_specifics_id.values())

seq_diags = []
for i in range(0,len(seq_diags_list):
   X = list(seq_diags_list[i].values())
   df = pd.concat(X[0],axis=1).T
   seq_diags.append(df)
```

This ends up giving a list of dataframes, where the length of each dataframe is represented in the number of diagnoses associated with each patient/id.

PS: It takes around 10 seconds to run for around 600,000 data points, so much better than before.